# How to include a cookiecutter template with a bdist/conda package?

Tags: python, setuptools, cookiecutter

I am maintaining an internal python package with a number of utility functions. As part of this package, I included a project generator `console_script` which calls cookiecutter using a custom template that is shipped with the package. This works fine when installing the package using `pip` (basically, as an sdist).

I am trying to get people to use `conda` as much as possible, so this is inconvenient as dependencies get resolved/installed using `pip`, not `conda`. Therefore, I am creating a conda package using the `python setup.py bdist_conda` way that is included by the Anaconda install. This works well, afaict, for another internal package.

However, when I try to create the present package, the `bdist_conda` creation byte-compiles all the python files in the package, so of course (but unintended) also the template files. This leads to a syntax error, because of the jinja strings, when running `python setup.py bdist_conda`:

```
  byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/dumb/home/bilderbuchi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mypkg/project_template/{{cookiecutter.project_name_simplified}}/{{cookiecutter.project_name_simplified}}.py to {{cookiecutter.project_name_simplified}}.cpython-35.pyc
  File "/path/to/mypkg/project_template/{{cookiecutter.project_name_simplified}}/{{cookiecutter.project_name_simplified}}.py", line 4
    {%- if cookiecutter.command_line_interface == 'argparse' %}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also can reproduce with a plain `python setup.py bdist`, so I can exclude conda from being the culprit here.
I add the template files with a `MANIFEST.in` containing `recursive-include mypkg/project_template *`, and `include_package_data = True` in the setuptools-based `setup.py`.

**Is there a (better) way to ship a cookiecutter template with some package? As I said, this works nicely when used with`pip`/sdist, but fails with `bdist`.
Alternatively, is there a way to suppress bdist byte-compiling a given set of files?**

The template cannot be placed online, which is why I want to include it in the package.
I also considered placing the template, separately, elsewhere, but then users depend on that location (e.g. network drive) being available when they use the project generator.
I looked at adding it as a zip file, but apart from this being super unconvenient from a version control point of view, [apparently](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#works-with-zip-files), users will be prompted to delete the existing (I guess unpacked to some user location) template on the next run, so I'd rather avoid that.

- Cookiecutter version: 1.6.0
- Python version: 3.5
- setuptools 38.5.1
- Operating System: Linux

Edit: I also posted this [in the cookiecutter issue tracker](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/issues/1049), but didn't get any feedback so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a fruitless search, I circumvent this issue by changing all my `.py` template files to `.pytemplate`. This avoids bdist/bdist_conda discovering them. I added a post_gen script that renames all the files back to `.py` after the project has been created from the template. Stupid workaround, but it works. :sigh:

I know that for bdist at least, compilation can be avoided by setting `sys.dont_write_bytecode`, but this workaround is not available for `bdist_conda`, see https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/686.